# Probability sitting at a round table

Tags: probability

What is the probability that 6 individuals will be seated correctly in order of their height when at a round table?

Is it 1/6!?

1 Because it can only be ascending or descending, and 6! on the bottom for all 6 possibilities?

Comment: Can you please show your own work so far?

Comment: Wrong question lol. I'm not sure if the answer is 1/6! or not

Comment: HINT It's a *round* table ...

Comment: Try fixing one person

Comment: How many possibilities do you have to arrange all others?

Comment: Does it matter if they are ordered clockwise or counterclockwise? Would either one be ok?

Comment: Yes, either is ok

Comment: So then it would make more sense to say "$2$ because it can be ascending *or* descending"!

Comment: So you would say 2/6! in that case?

Comment: One person is fixed...

Comment: No ... because it's a round table ... so is there only 1 starting point?

Comment: So how many people do you have to arrange?

Comment: @Bram you can fix one person and arrange all others

Comment: So in that case, 2/(6/6!)?

Comment: Yes, but this is just $\frac{2}{5!}$

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your guys' help

Comment: @IMOPUTFIE I know ... I was prompting the OP ...

Comment: Sorry- excuse my default

Comment: @IMOPUTFIE No problem! :)

Comment: @bot293 You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

We fix the first person and arrange all others. we have $5!$ possibilites for this arrangement- only two of these yield the wanted arrangement, thus the solution is $\frac{2}{5!}$

Answer (score -1):

Start with the tallest person. This person can sit in one of $6$ positions. Now, the next tallest can go either left or right of that person, so that's $2$ options there. The rest is now fixed.

So, it is $6 \cdot 2= 12$ out of $6!$, i.e. $\frac{12}{6!}$

Comment: Why the downvote?